# Not finding item in file

Tags: python, wxpython

Here is my code:

```
for line in open(logfile):
        if "ESSID" in line:
            begin = line.replace(" ", "")
            mid = begin.replace("ESSID:", "")
            final = mid.replace('"', "")
            print final
            self.APList.SetStringItem(self.index, 0, final)
            line = open(ilogfile).readline()
            if begin in line:
                connect = "yes"
            else:
                connect = "no"
            self.APList.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, connect)
```

here is the file it's scanning (well, one of them.):

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MomAndKids"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: E0:91:F5:7D:C9:14
      Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:603   Missed beacon:0
```

The main code I'm trying to test:

```
line = open(ilogfile).readline()
            if begin in line:
                connect = "yes"
            else:
                connect = "no"
```

I've tried using "final" instead of "begin" and reading the whole file instead of the first line (using both "final" and "begin" variables.) Neither worked. Why is this not working?

For full source, it is available at:
https://github.com/codywd/WiFiz/blob/master/main.py

Edit: The indentation is only broken in stackoverflow, not in the actual code.

Edit 2: The other file contains this:

```
wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: E0:91:F5:7D:C9:14
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MomAndKids"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000278820a146f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A4D6F6D416E644B696473
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
```

The relevant portion is at the top of that file.

Comment: By the way, take a look at [Wicd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wicd). It's written in Python, has Systemd support and does basically what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have, but I'm writing a frontend for netctl, which is why I'm rewriting a lot of the program. I'm trying to limit any dependencies, so the only dependencies (as of now) are python, and wxpython (and of course netctl)

Plus, since wicd is incompatible (requires uninstall, in fact) with netCFG, I assume it would be the same with netCTL

Comment: Look at `print repr(begin)` and `print repr(line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seemed to work fine:

```
line = open(ilogfile).readline()

if final.strip() in line.strip():
    connect = "yes"
else:
    connect = "no"
```